# F# how to join array of strings only when they're not null or whitespace

Tags: c#, arrays, f#, concatenation

I have the below F# code, which works to join 4 strings, separating with a space, only including those which aren't either null or entirely whitespace.

```ml
let street = 
    split.[5..8] 
    |> Array.filter (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace >> not)
    |> String.concat " "
```

This works really well, but is less performant than the below C# implementation of the same.

```
var street = "";
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(items[5]))
    street += items[5];
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(items[6]))
    street += string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(street) ? items[6] : " " + items[6];
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(items[7]))
    street += string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(street) ? items[7] : " " + items[7];
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(items[8]))
    street += string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(street) ? items[8] : " " + items[8];
return street;
```

Is there a way that I can achieve the same style of implementation in F#, instead of using the inline functions?

Comment: If you're looking for performance use StringBuilder.

Comment: thanks again @Gustavo - will put my implementation as answer - feel free to edit :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a variation that removes the explicit iteration and subscripting and could be modified to work for any collection that is a seq by passing in a sequence rather than referencing split directly.

```
let otherStreet = 
  let combine (sb:StringBuilder) (s:String) =
     if sb.Length = 0 then
        sb.Append s
     else
        (sb.Append " ").Append s

  split.[5..8] 
     |> Seq.filter (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace >> not)
     |> Seq.fold combine (StringBuilder())
     |> (fun sb -> sb.ToString())
```

Anytime I need to accumulate a result from a sequence I tend to use fold rather than explicit looping. There may be typos and/or thinkos in the code since I didn't have a compiler handy to verify it. I'll also bet that this version performs somewhat worse than your implementation but it can be made to work with non indexed collections easily as a tradeoff.

Comment: I've had some pretty poor performance from the Seq inline functions, I've found that while, for...in, and for...to loops yield the best performance. Not as nice to read, but ah well.

Comment: I agree that performance may be poor with the Seq functions. It depends heavily on whether the work done by the functions is large enough to overwhelm the overhead of the Seq functions. I usually write the code first with Seq expressions and then if the profiling shows it is a problem rewrite it into a more imperative form.

Comment: Thanks @Wayne - for the sake of performance, I'm going to stick with the solution I came up with, but appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Gustavo for suggesting StringBuilder :)

```ml
let otherStreet =
    let sb = new StringBuilder()
        for i = 5 to 8 do
            if not (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace split.[i]) then
                if sb.Length = 0 then
                    sb.Append split.[i] |> ignore
                else
                    sb.Append " " |> ignore
                    sb.Append split.[i] |> ignore
    sb.ToString()
```

Comment: Did this actually fix the performance problem?  And how does it compare to a StringBuilder-based C# implementation?  We're all assuming that the performance penalty is in the string concatenation itself, but that assumption may not be entirely correct.

Comment: with the only change being the string concatenation, the relevant timings for 1m records were:
 - using sprintf - 3456ms
 - using String.Format - 2989ms
 - using StringBuilder - 2614ms

The C# implementation, using a stringbuilder takes 2655ms

Answer (score 0):

If you want to traverse the array only once, then this approach might work for you:

```
let street = Array.fold (fun x y -> if white y then x elif x="" then x+y else x+" "+y) ""
street (split.[5..8])
```

where 'white' stands for 'String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace'.

Comment: even replaceing "white" with "String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace", this doesn't compile?

Comment: I assume that your 'String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace' has signature string -> boole. It works with e.g. 'let white s = s=""||s=" " '